# Rails accessing variable in email template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, actionmailer

I'm still on the rather steep side of the Rails learning curve, so please pardon the rather simplistic nature of this question, but Google's just not proving very helpful.

So, my issue is this. I have a controller that is calling a mailer. (Code snippet below)
The problem I can't seem to get passed is that no matter how I try to access the values in the rhtml page, I either get errors or nothing at all.

This is the controller snippet (@person is working just fine. @item is what's not working)

```
if params[:id] == 'username'
  item_value = @user[:login]
elsif params[:id] == 'password'
  item_value = @user[:new_password]
end

@item = { 'name' => params[:id], 'val' => item_value }
ApplicantMailer.deliver_forgot(@person.email, @person, @item)
```

This is the mailer method snippet:

```
def forgot(recipient, person, item, sent_at = Time.now)
  @subject         = 'Site Password Retrieval'
  @body['person']  = person
  @body['item']    = item
  @recipients      = 'rdavis@localhost'
  @from            = CONTACT_EMAIL
  @sent_on         = sent_at
  @headers         = {}
  logger.debug @body.to_yaml
end
```

This is the rhtml snippet:

```
Dear <%= @person.first_name %>,

You are receiving this email because you or someone else has used the lost <%= @item[:name] %> page from the login page.

Your <%= @item[:name] %> for your account is: <%= @item[:val] %>
```

So, like I said, when I try to access the values for the @item, if I use @item.name it throws a missing method error and if I use the version listed above, it doesn't show anything.

I know I'm working with a hash & thought that trying to access the keys like I showed here was the right way. Obviously, I'm missing something here.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please? Thanks!

Comment: I tried item[:name] & item[:value] and get the missing method error for that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using strings when creating your hash and symbols when accessing it.

You want the following:

```
@item = { :name => params[:id], :val => item_value }
```

Which is distinct from:

```
@item = { 'name' => params[:id], 'val' => item_value }
```

You can try this in `irb` with the following.

```
hash = {"a" => "val1", :a => "val2", "b" => "val3"}
hash["a"] => "val1"
hash[:a]  => "val2"
hash["b"] => "val3"
hash[:b]  => nil
```

Comment: Wow! I knew it had to be something simple. A bit embarrassed, but feel grateful for the answer and the addition to my learning of Rails. Thank you, Gazler! Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Skittles You many find the following blog post useful.  http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/

Comment: Thank you very much for this, Gazler! You're help was exactly what the doctor ordered. :)